# What AWS service limit governs Lambda/SQS event source mapping?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk

I have a Lambda defined in CDK for which I wish to receive events posted to a SQS queue.

```
SingletonFunction myLambda = ...

myLambda.addEventSource(SqsEventSource.Builder.create(mySqsQueue)
                                            .batchSize(1)
                                            .build())
```

When I deploy my stack, I am seeing periodic 429 throttling errors in the CloudFormation logs, always pointing to this particular mapping `AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping`:

> Rate exceeded for operation 'Rate exceeded (Service: Lambda, Status
> Code: 429, Request ID: 83c3e124-065b-41c9-8bb0-d3a57d07216b, Extended
> Request ID: null)'.

What service limit quota do I need to request be increased in order to stop this from happening?

Comment: Can you check your lambda metrics for throttles? 

It may be that your exceeding the default 1000 concurrent lambda executions per account limit.

See the following:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-troubleshoot-throttling/
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/05/aws-lambda-raises-default-concurrent-execution-limit/#:~:text=AWS%20Lambda's%20default%20concurrent%20execution,a%20given%20region%20per%20account.

Comment: do you get the error during deployment or after? How long/size of the queue? Did you limit the concurrency of your lambda? (you should, otherwise, you can impact other lambdas in your account). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lambda-service.html#limits_lambda those are the only two limits lambda has, that can be increased

Comment: This error occurs in deployment only - the number of concurrent executions has already been increased to 2000.

Comment: interesting, if it is during deployment I don't see how concurrency limit could be the problem. I'd try cdk destroy and re deploy or create a new account and see if the error persists. Unfortunately the error message seems pretty useless.

Maybe it is the size of your lambda, doesn't really make sense with the error message but worth checking out.

here are all lambda limits. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html

the lambda can't be bigger than 50MB

Comment: Are you using multiple Lambda deployments in parallel? 
Looking at the AWS Lambda limitations https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-failure-handling-features-for-kinesis-and-dynamodb-event-sources it looks like it's part of `Remainder of the control plane API requests (excludes invocation, GetFunction, and GetPolicy requests)` limitations. 

You can read a more thorough post on Lambda limitations here - https://lumigo.io/aws-lambda-performance-optimization/aws-lambda-limits/